# Attribute Based access control with Hyperledger-Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, abac

I have pulled fabric-repository from master branch. Using node-SDK

1. I am trying to register a user and enroll him with an attribute hf.registrar.Role attribute and requesting the certificate with the same attribute
2. Then I am invoking a transaction and trying to decode his attribute in chaincode
3. I am also trying to decode his attribute in at node layer
   But I am getting attribute as null and attribute status as false

   ```
     var  attr1_req={name:"hf.Registrar.Roles",required:true};
    attr_req.push(attr1_req);
    var attr_req=[];

    var reg_attr=[];
    var attr_reg={name:"hf.Registrar.Roles",value:"this is roles"};
    reg_attr.push(attr_reg);


   return hfc.newDefaultKeyValueStore({
       path: getKeyStoreForOrg(getOrgName(userOrg))
   }).then((store) => {
       client.setStateStore(store);
       // clearing the user context before switching
       client._userContext = null;
       return client.getUserContext(username, true).then((user) => {
           logger.debug("User :"+user)
           if (user && user.isEnrolled()) {
               logger.info('Successfully loaded member from persistence');
               return user;
           } else {
               let caClient = caClients[userOrg];
               logger.debug("Ca client: "+caClient)
               return getAdminUser(userOrg).then(function(adminUserObj) {
                   member = adminUserObj;

                   return caClient.register({
                       enrollmentID: username,
                        affiliation: userOrg + '.department1',
                        attrs:reg_attr
                   }, member);
               }).then((secret) => {
                   enrollmentSecret = secret;
                   logger.debug(username + ' registered successfully');
                   return caClient.enroll({
                       enrollmentID: username,
                       enrollmentSecret: secret,
                       attr_reqs:attr_req

                   });
               }, (err) => {
                   logger.debug(username + ' failed to register');
                   return '' + err;
                   //return 'Failed to register '+username+'. Error: ' + err.stack ? err.stack : err;
               }).then((message) => {
                   if (message && typeof message === 'string' && message.includes(
                           'Error:')) {
                       logger.error(username + ' enrollment failed');
                       return message;
                   }
                   logger.debug(username + ' enrolled successfully');

                   logger.debug("message :"+message.certificate);
                   let cert = X509.parseCert(message.certificate);
                   logger.debug("parsed cert: "+cert);
                   logger.debug("cert extensions ")
                   logger.debug(cert.extensions)
                   logger.debug("cert extensions[......] "+cert.extensions['1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1'])
                   if(cert && cert.extensions && cert.extensions['1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1']) {
                       logger.debug("reached line 324 member")
                       let attr_string=cert.extensions['1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1'];
                       let attr_object = JSON.parse(attr_string);
                       let attrs = attr_object.attrs;
                       logger.debug("attributes: "+attrs)
                   }
   ```

From chaincode part:
This is the code in chaincode

```
attrvalue,status,_:=cid.GetAttributeValue(stub,"hf.Registrar.Roles")
    fmt.Printf("attr Value: %s status : %t", attrvalue ,status)
    fmt.Println("attr Value: %s status : %t", attrvalue ,status)
```

From Node part:
Cert.extension is

```
 { keyUsage: 'Digital Signature',
  basicConstraints: 'CA:FALSE',
  subjectKeyIdentifier: 'F3:66:26:E7:0D:1A:15:E9:F0:40:6F:FF:17:A8:5C:D3:CE:B8:4C:50',
  authorityKeyIdentifier: 'keyid:8D:0F:3C:42:48:8D:31:FE:72:06:99:4D:CE:1D:25:4E:A1:8C:DA:47:85:24:73:51:91:D4:CF:93:D6:7D:48:B2' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved 
Steps

1. paste https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/release/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClientImpl.js to node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib
2. Clone fabric-ca from master branch and give `make clean` & `make docker`
3. clone fabric from master branch